# Updating RavenDB document from .Net API

Tags: .net, ravendb

I am trying to update a Person document in a Raven database, but am losing the reference to it when assigning the new object.  I can only get property-level assignment to work.

```
public void Put(int id, [FromBody]Person value)
    {
        var doc = RavenSession.Load<Person>(Qualify(id));

        if (doc == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        else
        {
            doc.FirstName = value.FirstName; //<-- doing it this way works
            doc = value;                     //<-- doing it this way doesn't
            RavenSession.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Obviously, the last thing I want to do is to have to iterate through all of the properties individually (especially since the actual implementation of this is in a Generic parent class)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because it you are replacing the entire doc (which is being tracked by Raven since you loaded it from Raven) with a new object that Raven doesn't know about.

A generic solution that is not specific to Raven is to use some kind of mapping library such as [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) or [ValueInjector](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) both of which are available on NuGet.

With ValueInjector you just replace

```
doc = value;
```

with

```
doc.InjectFrom(value);
```

And the appropriate using:

```
using Omu.ValueInjecter;
```

This maps all the properties from `value` into `doc`

Comment: For AutoMapper use Mapper.Map(source, destination) or Mapper.DynamicMap(source, destination)

Answer (score 1):

You could always evict the original document, and save the new one with:

```
RavenSession.Advanced.Evict(doc);
RavenSession.Store.Evict(value);
```